# Deeper understanding of the adjoint of a linear operator

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, hilbert-spaces, quantum-mechanics, quantum-computation

My undergraduate classes in Q.M describes the adjoint of a linear operator purely as a mathematical formality.
At this point, I'd like a deeper and heuristic understanding of it.

My questions are based on page 24 and 28 of the text *An introduction to quantum computing* by P. Kaye.

> > Page 24 outlines the definition of the dual of a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}^{*}$
> >
> > Definition: Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a Hilbert space. The Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}^{*}$ is defined as the set of linear maps $\mathcal{H} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$. We denote elements of $\mathcal{H}^{*}$ by $\langle \mathcal{X} |$, where the action of $\langle \mathcal{X} |$ is $\langle \mathcal{X} | : | \psi \rangle \mapsto \langle \mathcal{X} | \psi \rangle \in \mathbb{C}$.

Indeed, the Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}^{*}$ is just the space of all linear function - each of which with a corresponding *row vector form* or dual vector  - that maps a vector from $\mathcal{H}$ to $\mathbb{C}$ by contracting a *bra* and a *ket*, or, if you're a mathematician, a row vector with a column vector.

> > On page 28,
> >     Each map in $\mathcal{H}^{*}$ corresponds to some vector $\langle{\phi'} | $. The adjoint of the operator $T$, denoted $T^{\dagger}$, is defined as the linear map that sends 
> >     $\langle {\phi} |$ to $\langle {\phi'} |$, where $\langle \phi | (T |\psi \rangle) = \langle \phi ' |\psi \rangle$.

First, by definition, any linear operator on $\mathcal{H}^{*}$ maps dual vectors in $\mathcal{H}^{*}$ to $\mathbb{C}$ so this appears to contradicts the statement made by the author that the adjoint $T^{\dagger}$ maps elements in $\mathcal{H}$ to $\mathcal{H}$.

Second, if the aforementioned is true, how does this validates the claim that $\langle \phi | (T |\psi \rangle) = \langle \phi ' |\psi \rangle$?

Comment: To me, the adjoint story is MUCH more understandable in normal, everyday linear algebra notation instead of bra-ket notation.

Comment: Try reading this page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose_of_a_linear_map

Comment: "By definition, any linear operator on $\mathcal{H}^*$ maps dual vectors in $\mathcal{H}^*$ to $\mathbb C$" Absolutely not. The *elements* of $\mathcal{H}^*$ are linear maps $\mathcal{H}\rightarrow\mathbb C$. Linear operators on $\mathcal{H}^*$, by definition, are linear maps $\mathcal{H}^*\rightarrow\mathcal{H}^*$.

Comment: @eyeballfrog I may have overlooked this. Would you like to expand on this as an answer? I will accept your contribution and give it an upvote if you do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to help clear things up.

Let $f$ be a *continuous* linear map $\mathcal{H}\rightarrow \mathbb C$, and $\mathcal{H}^*$ be the set of all such maps. The [Riesz representation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_representation_theorem) shows that for each such $f$, there is a unique element $\left|\phi\right>$ of $\mathcal{H}$ such that $f(\left|\psi\right>) = \left<\phi\right.\left|\psi\right>$ for all $\left|\psi\right> \in \mathcal{H}$. We then make a small abuse of notation and identify $f$ with $\left<\phi\right|$. The Riesz theorem also shows that $\mathcal{H}^*$ is itself a vector space, and that the map $\mathcal{H}\rightarrow \mathcal{H}^*$ defined by $\left|\phi\right> = \left<\phi\right|$ is antilinear (it preserves addition and replaces scalar multiplication by scalar multiplication by the complex conjugate).

Now suppose $T:\mathcal{H}\rightarrow\mathcal{H}$ is a linear operator on $\mathcal{H}$. It can be shown that there is another linear operator $T^\dagger:\mathcal{H}\rightarrow\mathcal{H}$ such that $\left<\phi\right|(T\left|\psi\right>) = \left<T^\dagger\phi\right|(\left|\psi\right>)$ for all $\left|\psi\right> \in \mathcal{H}$ and $\left<\phi\right| \in \mathcal{H}^*$, and that this satisfies $T^{\dagger\dagger} = T$ and $(AB)^\dagger = B^\dagger A^\dagger$ (Exercise: prove this). We then use this to define a corresponding linear operator on $\mathcal{H}^*\rightarrow \mathcal{H}^*$, which we will write in postfix notation: $\left<\phi\right|T^* = \left<T^\dagger\phi\right|$.

So why did we do all this? The point is that, with this notation, for every linear operator $T$ on $\mathcal{H}$ and for all for all $\left|\psi\right> \in \mathcal{H}$ and $\left<\phi\right| \in \mathcal{H}^*$, we have $\left<\phi\right|(T\left|\psi\right>) = (\left<\phi\right|T^*)(\left|\psi\right>)$. This means we can drop the parentheses and the $^*$ and have an unambiguous symbol: $\left<\phi\right|T\left|\psi\right>$. Whether we interpret this as $T$ acting on $\left|\psi\right>$ (making it equal to $\left<\phi|T\psi\right>$) or $T^*$ acting on $\left<\phi\right|$ (making it equal to $\left<T^\dagger\phi|\psi\right>$) doesn't matter--we get the same result regardless. And this even works with compound operators:
$$
\left<\phi\right|AB\left|\psi\right> = \left<\phi\right|A\left|B\psi\right> = \left<A^\dagger\phi\right|B\left|\psi\right> = \left<\phi|AB\psi\right> = \left< A^\dagger\phi|B\psi\right> = \left< B^\dagger A^\dagger\phi|\psi\right> = \left< (AB)^\dagger \phi|\psi\right>.
$$
This completes the analogy to matrix notation in finite-dimensional vector spaces, where we write the inner product of two vectors $(x,y)$ as $x^Ty$, and for a linear operator $A$, we can unambiguously write $x^TAy$ to represent both $(x,Ay)$ and $(A^Tx,y)$.